# Getting error: Bad file descriptor: ***stack smashing detected*** at writing in client socket, but socket descriptor is correct

Tags: c, file, sockets, file-descriptor

#### Code Description

I have a concurrent server using select() that spawns a child for every 2 clients connected and gets their name. Parent reads the name from the client's socket and sends it to the child through a pipe ( every child gets its own pipe to communicate with parent, stored in struct child_fd[], along with file descriptors of its 2 clients) who writes back to client.

#### Error

On line **297** (I have highlighted it in code like this : ----- !!! LINE 297 !!! ----- )(**145** in Minimal Reproductive)in server code when I write back to client I get the bad file descriptor error. I never close any socket in my program, and also, I print that player2_fd (player_fd = 7) before writing and it is correct: I also printed it when the connection is made on line **141** (***25*** in Minimal reproductive) with accept() and it' also 7.
Moreover, even in the moment I send this descriptor from parent to child through pipe it is also 7.

#### Observation

The only difference between the first client and the second is that the first one's descriptor is given to fork child in the moment of forking( as it duplicates all variables) and the second one is sent through the pipe.

#### MINIMAL REPRODUCTIVE EXAMPLE SERVER CODE:

```
int main ()
{
    

    struct {
        int player1_fd, player2_fd, pipe[2];

    }child_fd[20];

   // CODE FOR CONNECTION: listen(), bind()...

    /* servim in mod concurent clientii... */
    while (1)
    {
        if (select (nfds+1, &readfds, NULL, NULL, NULL) < 0)
        {
            perror ("[server] Eroare la select().\n");
            return errno;
        }
        
        if (FD_ISSET (sd, &readfds)) {
           
            // ----- !!! LINE 25 !!! ------ //
            
            client = accept(sd, (struct sockaddr *) &from, &len);

            /* eroare la acceptarea conexiunii de la un client */
            if (client < 0) {
                perror("[server] Eroare la accept().\n");
                continue;
            }

            if (nfds < client) /* ajusteaza valoarea maximului */
                nfds = client;

            /* includem in lista de descriptori activi si acest socket */
            FD_SET (client, &actfds);

            printf("[server] S-a conectat clientul cu descriptorul %d, de la adresa %s.\n", client, conv_addr(from));
            fflush(stdout);
            clientCounter++;

            if (clientCounter % 2 == 1)       // if it's a player waiting for opponent
            {
                child_fd[nrOfChilds].player2_fd = -1;           // player2_fd is not known yet
                child_fd[nrOfChilds].player1_fd = client;       // remember it's fd (need it in match handler child)


                if (-1 == pipe(child_fd[nrOfChilds].pipe)) {
                    perror("Error at creating pipe\n");
                    return errno;
                }

                if (-1 == (pid = fork())) {
                    perror("Error at fork.\n");
                    return errno;
                }
                if (pid == 0) {     // [child that handles a chess match]
                    /* child only needs it's own information from the struct so I will create local variables*/
                    int p[] = {child_fd[nrOfChilds].pipe[0], child_fd[nrOfChilds].pipe[1]},
                            player1_fd = child_fd[nrOfChilds].player1_fd,
                            player2_fd = child_fd[nrOfChilds].player2_fd;
                    int infoFromPipe;
                    char msgrasp[20]=" ";
                    printf("pipe: %d %d", p[0],p[1]);
                    fflush(stdout);
                    while(1)
                    {
                        if (-1 == read(p[0], &infoFromPipe, sizeof(int)))
                        {
                            perror("Error at reading from pipe\n");
                            return errno;
                        }
                        printf("--%d--", infoFromPipe);
                        fflush(stdout);
                        if (infoFromPipe == 1) {      // means there is a fd for player2 coming

                            if (-1 == read(p[0], &player2_fd, sizeof(int)))
                            {
                                perror("Error at reading from pipe\n");
                                return errno;
                            }
                            printf("\np2 fd:%d\n", player2_fd);
                            fflush(stdout);
                        }

                        else
                        {       // both players connected

                            int player;
                            if (-1 == read(p[0], &player, sizeof(int)))     // reading the player int
                            {
                                perror("Error at reading from pipe\n");
                                return errno;
                            }
                            printf("player:%d\n",player);
                            fflush(stdout);
                            if ( player == 1){
                                
                                // EXACTLY THE SAME AS FOR PLAYER 2

                                }

                            }
                            else{       //player 2
                                int nameOrMove;
                                if (-1 == read(p[0], &nameOrMove, sizeof(int)))     // reading the name or move int
                                {
                                    perror("Error at reading from pipe\n");
                                    return errno;
                                }
                                printf("nameormove:%d\n",nameOrMove);
                                fflush(stdout);
                                if (nameOrMove == 0) {         // name
                                    int bytesRead, playerNameLen = 0;
                                    char playerName[20],c;
                                    bzero(playerName,20);

                                    if( -1 == read(p[0], &playerNameLen, sizeof(int)))
                                    {
                                        perror("Error at reading from pipe.\n");
                                        return errno;
                                    }
                                    if( -1 == read(p[0], playerName, playerNameLen))
                                    {
                                        perror("Error at reading from pipe.\n");
                                        return errno;
                                    }

                                    printf("Playername: %s\n", playerName);
                                    fflush(stdout);
                                    //mesaj de raspuns pentru client

                                    bzero(msgrasp,100);
                                    strcat(msgrasp,"Hello ");
                                    strcat(msgrasp,playerName);

                                    printf("[server]Trimitem mesajul inapoi...%s\n",msgrasp);
                                    fflush(stdout);
                                    printf("p2fd: %d\n", player2_fd);
                                    fflush(stdout);
                                    
                                    // ----- !!! LINE 145 !!! ----- //
                                    if(-1 == write(player2_fd, msgrasp, sizeof(msgrasp)))
                                    {
                                        perror("Error at writing to player1");
                                        return errno;
                                    }
                                    printf("Player name sent\n");
                                    fflush(stdout);

                                }
                            }

                        }
                    }



                }
                nrOfChilds++;

            } else {     // if it's the second player to be assigned to a waiting player 1
                if (pid > 0) {
                    
                    int x = 1;
                    if (-1 == write(child_fd[nrOfChilds-1].pipe[1], &x, sizeof(int)))
                    {
                        perror("Error at writing in pipe\n");
                        return errno;
                    }
                    if (-1 == write(child_fd[nrOfChilds-1].pipe[1], &client, sizeof(int)))       //sending player2 socket descriptor to it's child process handler
                    {
                        perror("Error at writing in pipe\n");
                        return errno;
                    }
                    child_fd[nrOfChilds-1].player2_fd = client;       //adding it to struct so the parent knows both players associated to each child process
                }
            }
        }
        /* vedem daca e pregatit vreun socket client pentru a trimite raspunsul */
        if (pid > 0) {
            for (fd = 0; fd <= nfds; fd++)    /* parcurgem multimea de descriptori */
            {
                /* este un socket de citire pregatit? */
                if (fd != sd && FD_ISSET (fd, &readfds)) {

                    for(int i = 0; i< nrOfChilds; ++i){         // looking for the child process to whom the client is associated
                        if ( fd == child_fd[i].player1_fd || fd == child_fd[i].player2_fd){

                            // READING FROM CLIENT SOCKET, SENDING PLAYER NAME TO CHILD 



                            }
                            FD_CLR(fd, &actfds);

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        /* for */
    }
}               /* while */
/* main */
```

#### Server code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

/* portul folosit */

#define PORT 2726

extern int errno;       /* eroarea returnata de unele apeluri */

/* functie de convertire a adresei IP a clientului in sir de caractere */
char * conv_addr (struct sockaddr_in address)
{
    static char str[25];
    char port[7];

    /* adresa IP a clientului */
    strcpy (str, inet_ntoa (address.sin_addr));
    /* portul utilizat de client */
    bzero (port, 7);
    sprintf (port, ":%d", ntohs (address.sin_port));
    strcat (str, port);
    return (str);
}

/* programul */
void sayHello(int);
int main ()
{
    struct sockaddr_in server;  /* structurile pentru server si clienti */
    struct sockaddr_in from;
    fd_set readfds;     /* multimea descriptorilor de citire */
    fd_set actfds;      /* multimea descriptorilor activi */
    struct timeval tv;      /* structura de timp pentru select() */
    int sd, client;     /* descriptori de socket */
    int optval=1;           /* optiune folosita pentru setsockopt()*/
    int fd, clientCounter = 0, nrOfChilds = 0, txt_fd;          // descriptor folosit pentru
    pid_t pid = 1;             //parcurgerea listelor de descriptori
    int nfds;           /* numarul maxim de descriptori */
    int len;            /* lungimea structurii sockaddr_in */
    bool waitingForOpponent;

    struct {
        int player1_fd, player2_fd, pipe[2];

    }child_fd[20];

    bzero(child_fd, sizeof(child_fd));
    if(-1 == mkfifo("my_fifo", 0600) ) {
        if (errno == EEXIST) {
            printf("Using already existent fifo: \"my_fifo\" ...\n");
        } else {
            perror("Error at creating \"my_fifo\" file.\n");
            exit(1);
        }

    }
    /* creare socket */
    if ((sd = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1)
    {
        perror ("[server] Eroare la socket().\n");
        return errno;
    }

    /*setam pentru socket optiunea SO_REUSEADDR */
    setsockopt(sd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR,&optval,sizeof(optval));

    /* pregatim structurile de date */
    bzero (&server, sizeof (server));

    /* umplem structura folosita de server */
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl (INADDR_ANY);
    server.sin_port = htons (PORT);

    /* atasam socketul */
    if (bind (sd, (struct sockaddr *) &server, sizeof (struct sockaddr)) == -1)
    {
        perror ("[server] Eroare la bind().\n");
        return errno;
    }

    /* punem serverul sa asculte daca vin clienti sa se conecteze */
    if (listen (sd, 5) == -1)
    {
        perror ("[server] Eroare la listen().\n");
        return errno;
    }

    /* completam multimea de descriptori de citire */
    FD_ZERO (&actfds);      /* initial, multimea este vida */
    FD_SET (sd, &actfds);       /* includem in multime socketul creat */

    tv.tv_sec = 1;      /* se va astepta un timp de 1 sec. */
    tv.tv_usec = 0;

    /* valoarea maxima a descriptorilor folositi */
    nfds = sd;

    printf ("[server] Asteptam la portul %d...\n", PORT);
    fflush (stdout);

    /* servim in mod concurent clientii... */
    while (1)
    {
        /* ajustam multimea descriptorilor activi (efectiv utilizati) */
        bcopy ((char *) &actfds, (char *) &readfds, sizeof (readfds));

        /* apelul select() */
        if (select (nfds+1, &readfds, NULL, NULL, NULL) < 0)
        {
            perror ("[server] Eroare la select().\n");
            return errno;
        }
        /* vedem daca e pregatit socketul pentru a-i accepta pe clienti */
        if (FD_ISSET (sd, &readfds)) {
            /* pregatirea structurii client */
            len = sizeof(from);
            bzero(&from, sizeof(from));

            /* a venit un client, acceptam conexiunea */


//  ----- !!! LINE 141 !!! -----

 
            client = accept(sd, (struct sockaddr *) &from, &len);

            /* eroare la acceptarea conexiunii de la un client */
            if (client < 0) {
                perror("[server] Eroare la accept().\n");
                continue;
            }

            if (nfds < client) /* ajusteaza valoarea maximului */
                nfds = client;

            /* includem in lista de descriptori activi si acest socket */
            FD_SET (client, &actfds);

            printf("[server] S-a conectat clientul cu descriptorul %d, de la adresa %s.\n", client, conv_addr(from));
            fflush(stdout);
            clientCounter++;

            if (clientCounter % 2 == 1)       // if it's a player waiting for opponent
            {
                child_fd[nrOfChilds].player2_fd = -1;           // player2_fd is not known yet
                child_fd[nrOfChilds].player1_fd = client;       // remember it's fd (need it in match handler child)


                if (-1 == pipe(child_fd[nrOfChilds].pipe)) {
                    perror("Error at creating pipe\n");
                    return errno;
                }

                if (-1 == (pid = fork())) {
                    perror("Error at fork.\n");
                    return errno;
                }
                if (pid == 0) {     // [child that handles a chess match]
                    /* child only needs it's own information from the struct so I will create local variables*/
                    int p[] = {child_fd[nrOfChilds].pipe[0], child_fd[nrOfChilds].pipe[1]},
                            player1_fd = child_fd[nrOfChilds].player1_fd,
                            player2_fd = child_fd[nrOfChilds].player2_fd;
                    int infoFromPipe;
                    char msgrasp[20]=" ";
                    printf("pipe: %d %d", p[0],p[1]);
                    fflush(stdout);
                    while(1)
                    {
                        if (-1 == read(p[0], &infoFromPipe, sizeof(int)))
                        {
                            perror("Error at reading from pipe\n");
                            return errno;
                        }
                        printf("--%d--", infoFromPipe);
                        fflush(stdout);
                        if (infoFromPipe == 1) {      // means there is a fd for player2 coming

                            if (-1 == read(p[0], &player2_fd, sizeof(int)))
                            {
                                perror("Error at reading from pipe\n");
                                return errno;
                            }
                            printf("\np2 fd:%d\n", player2_fd);
                            fflush(stdout);
                        }

                        else
                        {       // both players connected

                            int player;
                            if (-1 == read(p[0], &player, sizeof(int)))     // reading the player int
                            {
                                perror("Error at reading from pipe\n");
                                return errno;
                            }
                            printf("player:%d\n",player);
                            fflush(stdout);
                            if ( player == 1){
                                int nameOrMove;
                                if (-1 == read(p[0], &nameOrMove, sizeof(int)))     // reading the name or move int
                                {
                                    perror("Error at reading from pipe\n");
                                    return errno;
                                }
                                printf("nameormove:%d\n",nameOrMove);
                                fflush(stdout);
                                if (nameOrMove == 0) {         // name
                                    int bytesRead, playerNameLen = 0;
                                    char playerName[20],c;
                                    bzero(playerName,20);

                                    if( -1 == read(p[0], &playerNameLen, sizeof(int)))
                                    {
                                        perror("Error at reading from pipe.\n");
                                        return errno;
                                    }
                                    if( -1 == read(p[0], playerName, playerNameLen))
                                    {
                                        perror("Error at reading from pipe.\n");
                                        return errno;
                                    }

                                    printf("Playername: %s\n", playerName);
                                    fflush(stdout);
                                    //mesaj de raspuns pentru client

                                    bzero(msgrasp,100);
                                    strcat(msgrasp,"Hello ");
                                    strcat(msgrasp,playerName);

                                    printf("[server]Trimitem mesajul inapoi...%s\n",msgrasp);
                                    fflush(stdout);
                                    if(-1 == write(player1_fd, msgrasp, sizeof(msgrasp)))
                                    {
                                        perror("Error at writing to player1");
                                        return errno;
                                    }
                                    printf("Player name sent\n");
                                    fflush(stdout);

                                }

                            }
                            else{       //player 2
                                int nameOrMove;
                                if (-1 == read(p[0], &nameOrMove, sizeof(int)))     // reading the name or move int
                                {
                                    perror("Error at reading from pipe\n");
                                    return errno;
                                }
                                printf("nameormove:%d\n",nameOrMove);
                                fflush(stdout);
                                if (nameOrMove == 0) {         // name
                                    int bytesRead, playerNameLen = 0;
                                    char playerName[20],c;
                                    bzero(playerName,20);

                                    if( -1 == read(p[0], &playerNameLen, sizeof(int)))
                                    {
                                        perror("Error at reading from pipe.\n");
                                        return errno;
                                    }
                                    if( -1 == read(p[0], playerName, playerNameLen))
                                    {
                                        perror("Error at reading from pipe.\n");
                                        return errno;
                                    }

                                    printf("Playername: %s\n", playerName);
                                    fflush(stdout);
                                    //mesaj de raspuns pentru client

                                    bzero(msgrasp,100);
                                    strcat(msgrasp,"Hello ");
                                    strcat(msgrasp,playerName);

                                    printf("[server]Trimitem mesajul inapoi...%s\n",msgrasp);
                                    fflush(stdout);
                                    printf("p2fd: %d\n", player2_fd);
                                    fflush(stdout);

// ----- !!! LINE 297 !!! -----
 
                                    if(-1 == write(player2_fd, msgrasp, sizeof(msgrasp)))
                                    {
                                        perror("Error at writing to player1");
                                        return errno;
                                    }
                                    printf("Player name sent\n");
                                    fflush(stdout);

                                }
                            }

                        }
                    }



                }
                nrOfChilds++;

            } else {     // if it's the second player to be assigned to a waiting player 1
                if (pid > 0) {
                    /* All messages from parent to it's children processes will start with a char
                     * that shows if it's information coming from an already connected player or the fd of a new connection:
                     * '0' - old client
                     * '1' - new client
                     *      If the first char = '0', it will be followed by a char specifying from which player is the info coming from:
                     *      '1' - player1
                     *      '2' - player2
                     *             The third char tells me if I'm getting the name of the player or a move:
                     *             '0' - name
                     *             '1' - move
                     */
                    int x = 1;
                    if (-1 == write(child_fd[nrOfChilds-1].pipe[1], &x, sizeof(int)))
                    {
                        perror("Error at writing in pipe\n");
                        return errno;
                    }
                    if (-1 == write(child_fd[nrOfChilds-1].pipe[1], &client, sizeof(int)))       //sending player2 socket descriptor to it's child process handler
                    {
                        perror("Error at writing in pipe\n");
                        return errno;
                    }
                    child_fd[nrOfChilds-1].player2_fd = client;       //adding it to struct so the parent knows both players associated to each child process
                }
            }
        }
        /* vedem daca e pregatit vreun socket client pentru a trimite raspunsul */
        if (pid > 0) {
            for (fd = 0; fd <= nfds; fd++)    /* parcurgem multimea de descriptori */
            {
                /* este un socket de citire pregatit? */
                if (fd != sd && FD_ISSET (fd, &readfds)) {

                    for(int i = 0; i< nrOfChilds; ++i){         // looking for the child process to whom the client is associated
                        if ( fd == child_fd[i].player1_fd || fd == child_fd[i].player2_fd){

                            char nameOrMove;
                            if (-1 == read(fd, &nameOrMove, sizeof(char)))     // reading the name or move char
                            {
                                perror("Error at reading from pipe\n");
                                return errno;
                            }
                            if (nameOrMove == '0') {       // name
                                int bytesRead;
                                char playerName[20];
                                bytesRead = read (fd, playerName, sizeof (playerName));
                                if (bytesRead < 0)
                                {
                                    perror ("Eroare la read() de la client.\n");
                                    return errno;
                                }
                                int x = 0;
                                if ( -1 == write(child_fd[i].pipe[1], &x, sizeof(int))){
                                    perror("Error at writing in pipe\n");
                                    return errno;
                                }
                                x = (fd == child_fd[i].player1_fd) ? 1 : 2;
                                if ( -1 == write(child_fd[i].pipe[1], &x, sizeof(int))){
                                    perror("Error at writing in pipe\n");
                                    return errno;
                                }
                                x = 0;
                                if ( -1 == write(child_fd[i].pipe[1], &x, sizeof(int))){
                                    perror("Error at writing in pipe\n");
                                    return errno;
                                }
                                int playerNameLen = strlen(playerName);
                                if ( -1 == write(child_fd[i].pipe[1], &playerNameLen, sizeof(int))){
                                    perror("Error at writing in pipe\n");
                                    return errno;
                                }
                                if ( -1 == write(child_fd[i].pipe[1], playerName, playerNameLen)){
                                    perror("Error at writing in pipe\n");
                                    return errno;
                                }



                            }
                            FD_CLR(fd, &actfds);

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        /* for */
    }
}               /* while */
/* main */
```

Comment: Please provide [mcve]

Comment: This is a lot of code, but anyway this sounds like an out of range index for a local array, or a buffer overflow. Try to increase all array/buffer sizes by a factor 10 (like `char msg[100]` -> `char msg[1000]`) etc. If the problem goes away you know what to do.

Comment: Also avoid constructs like `char foo[100]; ...bzero (foo, 100);`, but rather use `bzero (foo, sizeof foo);` this will avoid size mismatches if you change the size of the `foo` array.

Comment: If it happens in `read()` or `write()` and friends, a bad socket FD wont' cause that. But a bad buffer address or length will.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I made your modifications and now I only get Bad file descriptor, no more ***stack smashing***

Comment: Now you need to check where and why you got the original stack smashing. What I suggested it not a solution to the problem, it just helps to find the actual problem.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I found why I was getting stack smash and I solved it, but i now realize they were actually 2 independent errors, and I still get the bad file descriptor (the program doesn't stop at the first error, just returns errno, thats why the stack smash error appears as well)

Comment: *Why* does your program continue after an error? especially a fatal error like this. Poor coding.

Comment: @user207421 I will treat errors properly at the end. I solved the stack error anyway so I'm left only with the bad file descriptor.

Comment: You seem to assume that file descriptors are global, and you can simply use the fd opened by a process in another process. There are ways to pass a fd from one process to another -- but they're a bit more involved than just passing its fd number through a pipe ;-) (google for SCM_RIGHTS, there are example of its use in the ssh source code, etc)

Answer (score 1):

One obvious bug that smashes the stack:

```
char msgrasp[20]=" ";
...
bzero(msgrasp,100);
```

Also don't use `bzero`, use standard C `memset`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, regarding this error I already solved it thanks to @Jabberwocky. I still have the bad file descriptor problem.